# How to have multiple, concurrent SqsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter polling queue?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-aws

I'm experiencing some really bad throughput issues with [`spring-integration-aws`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-aws)'s [SqsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-aws/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/aws/inbound/SqsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java), which is Spring Integration abstraction around [`spring-cloud-aws`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws)'s [`SimpleMessageListenerContainer`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/blob/master/spring-cloud-aws-messaging/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/aws/messaging/listener/SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java).

The issue, it seems, is that `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` can only request 10 messages at a time (an AWS limitation), and makes those requests incredibly slowly—in particular, I'm observing ~15 tps, which is way too slow.

Here's the code I have:

```java
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSAsync;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.listener.SqsMessageDeletionPolicy;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.integration.aws.inbound.SqsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.ExecutorChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor;

@Configuration
public class SqsConfiguration {
    // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ReceiveMessage.html#API_ReceiveMessage_RequestParameters
    private static final int SQS_RECEIVE_MAX_NUM_MESSAGES = 10;

    @Autowired
    private AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSAsync;

    @Bean
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor sqsThreadPoolTaskExecutor() {
        final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
        return threadPoolTaskExecutor;
    }

    @Bean
    MessageChannel receivedSqsMessageChannel() {
        return new ExecutorChannel(sqsThreadPoolTaskExecutor());
    }

    @Bean
    SqsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter sqsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter() {
        final SqsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter sqsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter = new SqsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter(amazonSQSAsync, "...");
        sqsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.setMessageDeletionPolicy(SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.NEVER);
        sqsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.setOutputChannel(receivedSqsMessageChannel());
        sqsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.setMaxNumberOfMessages(SQS_RECEIVE_MAX_NUM_MESSAGES);
        return sqsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter;
    }
}
```

`receivedSqsMessageChannel` is the input to a flow which eventually ends in the message's [`Acknowledgement#acknowledge()`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/blob/master/spring-cloud-aws-messaging/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/aws/messaging/listener/Acknowledgment.java) being called.

Given there's not yet any feature of `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` (and therefore `SqsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter`) to poll on multiple threads (there are [discussions](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/issues/166) for `spring-cloud-aws`, but it's far from close to being implemented, and after that, for `spring-integration-aws` to introduce support for it), and the TPS I have right now is unacceptable, I reason the best "fix" for now is to have multiple `SqsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter`s polling concurrently and outputting to `receivedSqsMessageChannel`.

How can I achieve this in Spring? Is there a way I can have a pool of `SqsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter`s running concurrently using Spring annotations?

Comment: Your performance could be impacted by the fact the listener will wait for all message processing worker threads to finish before fetching more messages off the queue https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/issues/166 The recommendation is to ensure your handler code is async. This way the @SqsListener method will return immediately, and the countdown latch will get to 0 very fast.